# How to set state from an external API in Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

In my store.js I init an object

```
let exchangeRates = {
    GBPtoUSD: 0, // American dollar
    GBPtoEUR: 0, // Euro
    GBPtoCAD: 0, // Canadian dollar
    GBPtoINR: 0, // Indian rupee
    GBPtoCHF: 0 //Swiss franc
}
```

Then I am setting its value with

```
function getExchangeRates() {
    return axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP&symbols=USD,EUR,CAD,CHF,INR')
                .then((response)=> {
                    exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD = response.data.rates.USD;
                    exchangeRates.GBPtoEUR = response.data.rates.EUR;
                    exchangeRates.GBPtoCAD = response.data.rates.CAD;
                    exchangeRates.GBPtoINR = response.data.rates.INR;
                    exchangeRates.GBPtoCHF = response.data.rates.CHF;
                })
                .catch((error)=> {console.log(error)})
}
```

My state gets values assigned like this

```
state: {
        GBPtoUSD: exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD, // American dollar
        GBPtoEUR: exchangeRates.GBPtoEUR, // Euro
        GBPtoCAD: exchangeRates.GBPtoCAD, // Canadian dollar
        GBPtoINR: exchangeRates.GBPtoINR, // Indian rupee
        GBPtoCHF: exchangeRates.GBPtoCHF //Swiss franc
    }
```

Then I set up getters, such as

```
getGBPtoUSD: state => {
            return state.GBPtoUSD;
        },
```

The problem is, when later on I am using calling that getter in my component like this

```
...mapGetters( [ "getGBPtoUSD" ] )
```

```
<li class="list-group-item py-3 ">
            {{ precise(userInputPrice) }}£ in USD is
            {{ precise(userInputPrice * getGBPtoUSD()) }} US dollars
</li>
```

I am getting getGBPtoUSD as 0 - the initial state.

How do I fix this so that state's value actually get assigned from outside? My approach to doing this clearly does not work.

**EDIT1**

Ok so doing

```
exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD = response.data.rates.USD;
      console.log(exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD)
```

logs the correct value of around 1.27. So where am I screwing up?

Comment: Where are you calling `getExchangeRates`? It is a vue method?

Comment: @waghcwb I am calling it in store.js where my Vuex.Store is defined. It's a regular js function.

Comment: Okay so this
 ```
exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD = response.data.rates.USD;
      console.log(exchangeRates.GBPtoUSD)
```
gives me the correct value of around 1.27.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this example on how to set the state from external service using axios

```js
// main.js

import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // create the state to store the data
  state: {
    todo: {}
  },

  // make an asynchronous call to get the data
  actions: {
    getTodoItem(state, index) {
      return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index}`);
    }
  },

  // set data in state
  mutations: {
    setTodo(state, value) {
      Vue.set(state, "todo", value);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  store, // loads the store
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<!-- App.vue -->

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["todo"]),
    hasTodo() {
      return Object.keys(this.todo).length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getTodoItem"]),
    ...mapMutations(["setTodo"]),

    async getTodo() {
      // random number between 1 and 200
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
      const { data } = await this.getTodoItem(index);
      this.setTodo(data);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTodo();
  }
};
</script>


<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="hasTodo">Todo: {{ todo.title }}</div>
    <b v-else>Loading..</b>
  </div>
</template>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-y69be

Comment: Ok, so... You are setting state with an action triggered from a component, yes?

Comment: @AleksanderJess, Exaclty, actions are made for async operations (like an http request), so we create an action to get the request data and then call a mutation to set it in the state.